# How to check if an IUnityContainer is consistent at runtime.

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to check a unity container after I am finished with all the types to see if somewhere a type was missing. Is there a reasonable way of doing this?

Here is some example code that illustrates what I want to do:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System;

namespace MSUnityTest
{
    public interface INamed
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
    public class GivenName : INamed
    {
        private string _name;
        public GivenName(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }
        public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    }

    public class NamePrinter
    {
        private INamed _entity;
        public NamePrinter(INamed entity) { _entity = entity; }
        public void run() { Console.WriteLine(_entity.Name); }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static IUnityContainer CheckedContainer()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            //suppose I forget the following line
            //container.RegisterType<INamed, GivenName>(new InjectionConstructor("Given Name"));
            //the container is now not in the State I want it to be
            container.RegisterType<NamePrinter, NamePrinter>();
            //can I detect that here?
            container.CheckTypesNowAndFailEarly(); //<-- this function does not exist
            return container;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckedContainer().Resolve<NamePrinter>().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to check if you missed a registration? And if so, how do you determine which registrations you should have done?

Comment: I want the container to throw if there is a type that the container can not resolve on its own. Or even better iterate through the registrations and assert that each one can be resolved (so I could potentially define exceptions if I really need them).

Comment: I found this link: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/12/21/TestingContainerConfigurations/